# Ruby on Rails div_for within an each block is not producing correct id and class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to generate some divs using div_for inside of an each block. The result is that every div has the same id and class. The documentation says that each div should have a unique id (which is what I want).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<% @pallet.boxes.each do |box| %>
 <%= div_for(box) do %>
  <h2><%= box.name %></h2>
  <p>some stuff in here</p>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here is a snippet of the page source:

```
<div class="box" id="new_box"> 
    <h2>box1</h2>
    <p>some stuff in here</p>           
</div>      

<div class="box" id="new_box"> 
    <h2>box2</h2>
    <p>some stuff in here</p>           
</div>

<div class="box" id="new_box"> 
    <h2>box3</h2>
    <p>some stuff in here</p>           
</div>
```

Comment: Could you paste please the output your getting, if `box` is an `ActiveRecord` it should work.

Comment: I just updated the post with a bit of my page source, is that what you needed? or some other kind of output? thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to do the following:

put the following code in a parital (_box.html.erb):

```
<%= div_for(box) do %>   
  <h2><%= box.name %></h2>   
  <p>some stuff in here</p>  
<% end %>
```

and call from your original file `<%= render @pallet.boxes %>`

I think that your problem is caused because you iterate 2 times on the same box element.
The pattern I posted above always works for me.